# Set up News source for Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I work for a publication and would like to find out how I can enable our site to be read by Google Home or if there's something I need to do to set that up. I've looked at the Google Assistant SDK but it seems to be geared more towards custom commands to your own device like a Raspberry Pi etc.

Thank you!

Comment: I've re-tagged this for the more appropriate API, as I describe in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the Google Assistant SDK is for building your own Assistant hardware.

The Actions on Google API is for building Actions that work with the Google Assistant on multiple platforms. With this, you can build an Action that responds to requests to "Hey Google, Talk to *your action name*". Google also reviews these Actions periodically to find ones that may more directly respond to questions such as "Hey Google, tell me the news".

There is currently no way to explicitly have your audio included as part of Google Assistant's "Good Morning" news briefing list, although Google may use RSS streams or other public feeds to make such content available.

**Update**

Google just announced formalizing what they call Content Actions, which are the formal way to get specific content such as poscasts, news, and recipes through the Assistant. See [the documentation for details](https://developers.google.com/actions/content-actions/), but in your case, they've documented what the RSS feed should look like.

Comment: Are you saying there is no way to create your own Google Home "news app?" I've been trying to find documentation on how to make a Google Home app that can be added to Google's news flash list.

Comment: That is correct. There is no equivalent of an Alexa "Flash Briefing" Skill. (At least not currently.)

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner I'll have to come back here once I try this!

Comment: It turns out there is new information from Google about how to do this. See the documentation.